# Implemented Nested Condition in Java Lambda or DecisionTree

Tags: java

I need to implement a complex set of rules that can be done by many nested conditions. I'm looking for a more elegant way to do it.What is the best practice?  Does Java Lambda support those cases? Is Decision Tree is the right way?

```
if(condition 1) {
  if (condition 2) {
   if (condition 3) {
    if (condition 4) {
     setValueToObject1();
    }
   } else //condition 3
    setValueToObject2();
  }
 }
 }
 } else {
  setValueToObject3();
 }
```

Comment: The good practice is not to indent more than three times. You can use de morgan rules

Comment: You don't need those many nests .. && operator is your friend.

Comment: and it seems to have a problem in your brackets, there is more close than open ones

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you consider using [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/). It allows matchers to be composed in flexible and extensible ways with high readability.

E.g.

```
if (allOf(m1, m2, m3)) {
    // TODO
}
```

Hamcrest is used a lot in unit testing but it's a general purpose library.